# Openshift MYSQL environment variables not set

Tags: mysql, openshift

all my MySQL environment variables result in an empty string such as 
echo getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL');
echo getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');

however the others such as 
echo getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME');
echo getenv('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR');

work perfectlly fine. Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious here but it always help to be clear. Are you sure that the mysql cartridge is added? You can run `rhc apps` to get a list of your applications and what cartridges their using. You can also check through the web console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, and tried creating and recreating Applications multiple times without success

The solution was to use Git to push the code to Openshift (at least one time), if you only use sFTP to push the code, those variables will not be accessible

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the rhc app stop & rhc app start commands to restart your application and the environment variables will then be provided to your application.  Make sure that you don't just use the rhc app restart command, as it doesn't not usually work, think of it as an apachectl stop/start vs apachectl reload.

Comment: In theory that should work, but I tried a restart from the openshift web interface, and this did not work. The git push process suggested in the other answer did however result in success.