# Openshift MySQL Environment vars not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I cant seem to get the MySQL Vars for Openshift to work in my PHP application.
I created a test.php file to try to get to the bottom of it.

**test.php**

```php
<?php
define( "DB_SERVER", getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
echo "Host1 define: ".DB_SERVER;
echo "<br>Host2 getenv: ". getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
echo "<br>Host3 _env: ". $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'];
echo "<br>Host4 _server: ". $_SERVER['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'];
echo "<br>Openshift App Name: ". $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'];
?>
```

**Output in browser:**

> Host1 define:
>   Host2 getenv:
>   Host3 _env:
>   Host4 _server:
>   Openshift App Name: web

I added in the Openshift App Name Var to show that some Openshift Vars are indeed working, but the MySQL ones are not for some reason.

PHP Cartridge version: 5.4
MySQL version: 5.5

Any ideas on how to further debug? I have started from a clean install, so this 
is very strange.

**Note:**

Running `echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` in the Openshift SSH console DOES give me an IP address for the host.
I have also tried restarting the cartridge from the Openshift admin page, no luck.

More than happy to give more info, I'm very keen on writing clear SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it! Do a git push to trigger the mysql vars to work.

Create a dummy file in your git directory (example below for linux), commit, then push:

```
touch test
git add test
git commit -m "Test file for triggering git push deploy process"
git push
```

Remember to delete the test file in your next commit.

Even though I had tried to restart the cartridge from the Openshift web control panel, the thing that solved it was to push 'something' to git, and something in that deploy process allowed those variables for mysql to work.

I found a answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898911/339803) that suggested to push to git at least once, but I didnt try that as I had already pushed to git to change the PHP DB config file from static values to $_ENV values. So I assumed that doing it again wouldnt help.

Nevertheless, as soon as I created a test file and pushed to git, the mysql variables worked.

Comment: Update: I realised I never did a push after changing the MYSQL vars to ENV, as I had changed the vars from static to dynamic using SSH to get to the Openshift Data directory. So the "2nd" push made it all work, when in fact it was the 1st push. (The DB settings are in the CMS (concrete5), and have to be in a persistent directory, outside of git) as concrete5 likes to manage these settings via its CMS. I couldn't use the CMS as the $_ENV variables would be wrapped in quotes. So I had to leave the config in the persistent dir, and edit there using command line.

Comment: This worked for me! Even though I had manually restarted my gear, the vars didn't get picked up by PHP until I did another Git push.